# Не могу передать переменную в google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, chrome-extension

Всем привет! Помогите с проблемой: хотел сделать простенькое расширение в хром, в этом практически полный 0 :). Мне нужно оперировать с адресной строкой, если конкретнее, то нужно по кликам по ссылкам из попапа перенаправлять на разные домены (некий переключатель локализаций). 
Так вот добавил я на все нужные страницы свой скрипт след содержания:

```
var host1 = location.pathname;
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({url: location.pathname});
```

в основном скрипте след:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    var urls = request.url;
  })


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        (function () {
            var ln = links[i];
            ln.onclick = function () {
                chrome.tabs.create({active: true, url: urls});
            };
        })();
    }
})
```

но в месте, где должна создаваться вкладка - ничего не происходит. Есть догадка, что сам url приезжает позже, чем формируются онклики, поэтому и не работат. Подскажите, что я не так делаю?

Спасибо!

Comment: Возможно дело в области видимости переменных, и она просто напросто не видна за пределами chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(). Но не уверен, сам не супер-специалист =( .

Comment: Что такое, в вашем понимании, "основной скрипт"?

Comment: Спасибо за попытку помочь! Вопрос уже не актуален, всё сделал.